# Qt designer Q PaintError

Tags: c++, qt, qt4

I have trouble with Qt4.

My Qt

```
Qt Creator 2.3.1 

Based on Qt 4.7.4 (32 bit)
```

2 days ago, I installed Qt designer and Opencv they work very well except one weird error.

This Error says that,

```
QWidget: Must construct a QApplication before a QPaintDevice
```

When I decleare any class in my main.cpp file This weird error occurs. For example,

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

MainWindow ana_pencere; // If I dont decleare, error dissappers.

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
   w.show();
 /** @function main */

  return a.exec();
 }
```

So, I dont have any idea why this error occurs.

If anyone help me, I will be appreciated.

Comment: Any reason to have two main windows? The way you create 'w' is the usual way to do it. Just omit the ana_pencere or make it a local variable declared after the QApplication a.

Comment: @FrankOsterfeld This was a problem investing case. I know I initialized 2 same class.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Before creating any QWidgets, you have to construct QApplication.

You're creating a global object, MainWindow, *before* main calls QApplication.

You can fix this by making it so that you simply have a global pointer to an object, and then assign it later, like this:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

MainWindow* ana_pencere_ptr; 
//Pointer to an object. Doesn't initialize an object.

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);
   MainWindow w;
   ana_pencere_ptr = &w;
   w.show();

 /** @function main */

  return a.exec();
 }
```

Basically, the line

```
QApplication a(argc, argv);
```

Has to come before other Qobjects. In the code you gave, global objects are initialized before main (and before you construct your QApplication), hence your problem.

Comment: Try to see if you could avoid global variables though.

Comment: thanks for answering. It works. But is there any way to initialize my class like global varible. I dont want to use my class with pointer type.

Comment: No, I don't believe there is. Pointers really work well once you know how to work with them.

You could use ana_pencere_ptr like this:

ana_pencere_ptr->update()

just as simply as you'd use a non-pointer ana_pencere like this:

ana_pencere.update()

The -> notation is very nice. Here's a little tutorial on pointers:
http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/pointers/

( (*ana_pencere_ptr).update() means the same thing as ana_pencere_ptr->update() )

Answer (score 0):

create a pointer or smart pointer and initialize instance of `MainWindow` after `QApplication`.

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

//only declare a pointer, no object is being created so far
boost::shared_ptr<MainWindow> ana_pencere_ptr; 

 int main(int argc, char *argv[])
 {
   QApplication a(argc, argv);

   ana_pencere_ptr.reset(new MainWindow);
   ana_pencere_ptr->show();

 /** @function main */

  return a.exec();
 }
```